# Twitter API limits

Tags: api, class, twitter

I made a website like wefollow.com. And I was using Abraham Williams (abrah.am)'s class to update user data(followers and tweets) every night. But after Twitter changed API limits I'm kind of stuck.

I'm limited to 150 or 200 requests for an hour. Which was 10,000 before. How can I update user data with these limits. Or is there any other class to solve this problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could cache it on your server, or pipe it through [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) and then set the [`_maxage`](http://www.yqlblog.net/blog/2010/03/12/avoiding-rate-limits-and-getting-banned-in-yql-and-pipes-caching-is-your-friend/) parameter sufficiently so it won't hit the Twitter API limit.

YQL has a 100,000 calls a day limit.

Answer (score 1):

Its 150 for unauthenticated users, and 350 for authenticated users. I don't think you can bypass this. Twitter was previously offering clients to be whitelisted (gets 30,000 requests per hour), but now they've removed that privilege.

So you're stuck with 350 x 24 requests per day. Its not a matter of changing libraries.

Comment: so how does wefollow.com handles that?

Comment: @GökhanD. We follow updates records over a period of time, It is probably caching the values. Plus in a day there's about 3600 calls available. And wefollow doesn't have that much of content.